# How to redirect to an external URL from an Angular2 route's canActivate in Chrome while maintaining Referrer?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, angular5, redirect, angular4-router

I may be slightly off with what's going on here because of how deeply Observers nest in Angular and the difficulties involved in debugging that sort of thing, but this is what I'm observing.

I have an Angular 5 application using @angular/router 5.2.6, I have a Guard service, I have an external SSO-type user authentication service.  If a user is not authenticated I need to be able to redirect out to my auth service, login if required, and come back to the SAME URL they were originally trying to get.

So I have routes setup and have my Guard service as the route's canActivate condition.  I use

```
window.location.href = "...";
```

to redirect away from my app to the auth service.  And also return false from the canActivate method after setting that redirect.

My auth service depends on the Referrer header to know where to send the user back to with a token after they're authenticated.  This works fine in most browsers but in Chrome, it seems like the browser is letting the entire event stack unroll before doing the redirect.

Which is to say that what seems to happen is:

1. `window.location.href = "...";`
2. canActivate returns false.
3. Because the route can't activate, the user is dropped to the app root.
4. A split second later, the redirect happens.

However because we landed on the app root FIRST, the Referrer header is wrong.

---

So what are my options here?

1. If I return true instead of false, the redirect does happen with the
   correct header but it's not the most secure thing.
2. If I use a query parameter with the original URL, I'd need an intermediary between my app and the auth service to translate that back into the Referrer header.
3. Instead of the window location I can create an Anchor tag with the auth service URL and programmatically click it.  This seems to short circuit the router and prevent canActivate from fully unrolling.

What else can I do?  Maybe some sort of Observable return waiting for popstate or hashchange and forcing the URL back?  Is there something I'm not seeing, do you think I even have the problem correct?

---

EDITS:  Adding the canActivate methods

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const url: string = state.url;

    if (this.authService.config.permissionsEndpointUrl && this.authService.config.hasUserPermissions) {
      // If permissions are configured, check both the user session token and user access permissions
      return this.checkLogin(url) && this.checkPermissions(route.data['permissions']);
    } else {
      // Otherwise, only check the user session token
      return this.checkLogin(url);
    }
  }



private checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    const currentUser = this.authService.getUserSessionDetails();
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token && this.authService.tokenNotExpired(currentUser.token)) {
      return true;
    }

    // Store the attempted URL for redirecting after login
    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

    this.authService.redirectToLogin(true);
    return false;
  }

redirectToLogin(guardMode: boolean = false): void {
...
        if (this.config.loginRoutePath) {
            window.location.href = this.config.loginRoutePath;
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your auth guard `canActivate` method? I'm thinking you can just filter out the false values in your return observable to prevent the rest of the observable chain from processing the request.

Comment: It calls through a few other methods, but I don't return an Observable to begin with, just a straight boolean value which is what makes this odder.  I can add them, though.  I'll probably need to anonymize them slightly.

Comment: I'm wondering if instead of returning right away after your checks in the if-else branches, that instead you held onto the result in a variable (i.e. `isAuthorized`) and then returned this at the bottom of your `canActivate` method: `return isAuthorized ? Observable.of(true) : Observable.empty();`

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel No luck doing that.  Acts the same, also tried a few Promise variations and they failed in new and creative ways.

Comment: It might not work because the observable ends up completing (could try a subject that never emits a value and doesn't complete). Did your promise variations never resolve when you were in a `false` state to just prevent it from doing further processing?